# Reasons why PL/SQL Developer's debugger won't enter a procedure?

Tags: debugging, plsql, plsqldeveloper, procedures, step-into

I am trying to debug a procedure using PL/SQL developer's built-in debugger.

After stepping over the `BEGIN`, when the debugger is over the actual procedure call, the "step-into" button will just execute the procedure without entering it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) The procedure (or the package containing the procedure) might not be compiled with debug info 2) the user running the debugger is not the owner of the package/procedure (you need the "debug any procedure" privilege to debug procedures  you don't own)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding debug information like @Carlo Sima mentioned.

Like this:

[image: Add debug information]

Comment: is it possible to add debug information on multiple packages?

Comment: Haven't seen anything like this in Pl/SQL's user guide. We could presume that just by  Left Ctrl + selecting all objects could do the job, but I guess you've already tried that.